# Why numba can't compile this for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.6, numba

I try to compute the 1-dimensional discrete cosine transformation (Type 2), I am trying to improve my performance with numba.
I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import numba

@numba.jit()
def epsilon(N:int, i: int) -> float:
    if i == 0 or i == N:
        return math.sqrt(2)/2
    return 1.0

@numba.jit()
def dct2(a):
    n = len(a)
    y = np.empty([2*n])
    y[:len(a)] = a
    y[n:] = np.flip(a)
    fft = np.fft.fft(y)
    erg = np.empty([n])
    factor = 1/math.sqrt(2*n)
    for i in range(0,n):
        erg[i] = factor*epsilon(n,i)*(math.cos(-i*2*math.pi/(4*n))*fft[i].real - math.sin(-i*2*math.pi/(4*n))*fft[i].imag)
    return erg
```

I think it can't compile the for loop, but I don't know why. From what I understand from the numba Documentation, the loop should be able to be lifted.

I got the following warnings:

```
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function empty>)
[2] During: typing of call at src/algos.py (32)


File "src/algos.py", line 32:
def dct2(a):
    <source elided>
    n = len(a)
    y = np.empty([2*n])
 ^

  @numba.jit()
src/algos.py:29: NumbaWarning: Function "dct2" failed type inference: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "src/algos.py", line 39:
def dct2(a):
    <source elided>
    factor = 1/math.sqrt(2*n)
    for i in range(0,n):
 ^

  @numba.jit()
src/algos.py:29: NumbaWarning: Function "dct2" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.
  @numba.jit()
src/algos.py:29: NumbaWarning: Function "dct2" failed type inference: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function empty>) with argument(s) of type(s): (list(int64))
 * parameterized
```

Does anyone know why the loop fails and how I might fix it?

Comment: probably needs to be  `y = np.empty(2*n)` without the brackets - numpy takes it either way, but numba can be more restrictive

Comment: `numpy.fft` does not seem to be currently supported by Numba. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: when i remove numpy.fft I still get warning about the loop.
np.empty without brackets does also nothing.

Comment: @Unlikus any joy?!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as @Eskapp pointed out, numba does not support some of the numpy methods, which apparently include fft.
Second, numba is very picky about the data types (since it is compiled into static typed code), so you should be specific to the maximum.

I would avoid initiating arrays without providing types, and do (omitting fft parts):

```
def dct2(a):
    n = len(a)
    y = np.empty(2*n, np.float64)
    y[:len(a)] = a
    y[n:] = np.flip(a)
    # fft = np.fft.fft(y)
    erg = np.empty(n, np.float64)
    factor = 1 / math.sqrt(2*n)
    for i in range(n):
        erg[i] = factor*epsilon(n,i)*(math.cos(-i*2*math.pi/(4*n)) - math.sin(-i*2*math.pi/(4*n)))
    return erg
```

I would expect this to compile and run.

Another note, any numpy method supported by numba has a specific implementation on numba side - including callee types. So calling np.empty() with an argument that is a 'list of integers' like [2 * n] instead of 2 * n, will raise you a quite self explanatory Typing error like this, since that signature is not implemented:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)No implementation of function Function(<built-in function empty>) found for signature: 
>>>empty(list(int64)<iv=None>, class(float64))
```